# How come R_LIBS_USER points into AppData\Roaming?

Tags: r

On one of our Windows computers where R is installed, `R_LIBS_USER` points to `C:\Users\username\AppData\Roaming\R\libraries`. The user cannot remember that they have set `R_LIBS_USER` explictly and insists that it must have been the installer. As you may know, setting an environment variable on Windows is a non-trival procedure. Therefore, I am inclined to believe the user that they did not do it themselves.

Is there some well-known agent, such as an R installer, a package, or a third-party software, that sets `R_LIBS_USER` to point into `AppData\Roaming\R`?

The R installer used was downloaded from [CRAN](https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/).

Comment: Ask to see the file `c:\users\username\documents\.Renviron`

Comment: @HongOoi That `.Renviron` file does not exist.